# Can't Install Android Packages: Failed to Fetch due to Connection

Tags: android

I'm getting a problem installing Android packages. I installed it initially with no problems. But decided to switch paths and install it else where.

Now I get the error:

Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-6.xml
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-6.xml, reason: Connection to http://127.0.0.1:8520 refused
Done loading packages.

On running in Windows 7 Ultimate, installed android-sdk_r18-windows to C:\Android
I tried https and http. both don't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the proxy server and ports, then the downloads will complete.